# Dynamically populate dropdown list without reloading page

Tags: php, mysqli

I've a table named `course`. 
which contains fields

```
COURSEID, COURSENAME
```

Another Table named `STUDENTS`. which contains

```
STCODE, STNAME, COURSEID
```

I've a preloaded Dropdown List of Courses. I'd like to populate the second Dropdown List with the students who are in the selected `course` from the first dropdown list without reloading the page.

Comment: well, please search how to use AJAX and Javascript Your question is something to be learned easily through many tutorials on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make an ajax call to perform this task on the change of first select box . below is the script. **you may need to include jquery library .**

```
  $(document).ready(function()
{

    $('.select').change(function()  // function will work when option will change in select
    {

        var course_id = $('.select').val();
        $.ajax({
        type:"post", 
      url: 'getdetail.php' ,     // url to the php file to get the response 
      data:'course_id='+  course_id,
      success: function(msg) {
          $('.select2').html(msg);

        }
        });
    })
})
```

html will look like this

```
<select class="select">
        <option value="1">Course1</option>
        <option value="2">Course1</option>
        <option value="3">Course1</option>  
    </select>

    <select class="select2">
        <option>select1</option>

    </select>
```

your php file will get the data from db . this should look something like this . `getdetail.php` this is just an example change this according to your need and db .

```
<?
    $course_id=$_REQUEST['course_id'];     // selected course id here 
    $sql_query="query here " ; // make an sql query to fetch the students from the course.  
    while($result)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$val."'>".$name."</option>"

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that your first dropdown has the value of course id unless and until that this becomes complicated:

```
$('select[name=\'course\']').on('change', function() {
    //fetch the course_id of the selected course
    course_id = $('select[name=\'course_id\']').val();

    $.ajax({
      //here sending your data to the file where the function will get your course_id and select students for it and then return it
      url: 'path_to_some_file.php' +  course_id,
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function(json) {
          //this is the success of the ajax. I have returned it in json format but you don't need to. send it in simple array but don't forget to return from the ajax function you called. Below lines is doing nothing but populating your student dropdown and then appending it to the dropdown.

          html = '<option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>';
          for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + json[i]['student_id'] + '"';
                html += '>' + json[i]['student_name'] + '</option>';
          }
          $('select[name=\'name_of_your_second_dropdown\']').html(html);

        }
    });
  });
```

h

Comment: I cannot get your coding.  Please explain in details.